# Duplicating text in a paragraph because of $(element).end()?

Tags: jquery, while-loop, paragraph

I have a `div` with a class `textareaedit` which can have more than one `p` (paragraphs) contained in it. But I want to grab only the last paragraph and deal with that text.

My HTML is like this:

```
<div class="textareaedit">
<p>  </p>
<p>  </p>
</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
$thisinput = $('forminput');

$taedit = $('.textareaedit');
    var $target = $taedit.children(); //in case there is more than one <p> here

  while( $target.length ) {
  $target = $target.children();
   }            

  $target.end().text($thisinput.val()) ;
```

This code is triggered whenever the user leaves focus on the form element `forminput`. I want the user's text to go to `$taedit`. But if `$taedit` happens to have more than one paragraph, then every time the user types in the `forminput`, then `$taedit` duplicates the text within it.

Example: 
If `$taedit` has only one `p`, then when user enters `This is my text`, then `$taedit` looks like this:

```
This is my text
```

But if `$taedit` happens to have two `p`, then when the user enters `This is my text` (just once!), then `$taedit` looks like this:

```
This is my text
This is my text
```

And if the user enters it again, it doubles:

```
This is my text
This is my text
This is my text
This is my text
```

I understand something must be happening because of the `while` loop, but what I don't understand is that I only call `$target.end()` once... so text should only be getting appended to the last paragraph? My objective is to have no duplicates, regardless of how many `p` there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the while loop at all? You can replace the while loop and the last statement with:

```
$target.last().text($thisinput.val());
```